# Issue mocking a Redux Store with Jest/redux-mock-store

Tags: react-native, react-redux, jestjs

I've been trying to mock a redux store which is inside a dependency module with no success as below:

```
//configStore.js
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers(reducers),
    undefined,
    composeEnhancers(
        autoRehydrate(),
        applyMiddleware(...middlewares)
        // other store enhancers if any
    )
);


export default store;
```

This store is used in a file like this one:

```
//module
import store from '../config/configStore';

export function reSeat() {

        let seat = store.getState().travelers[0].accommodations[0];

        //some logic
       store.dispatch(API_CALL);
       store.dispatch(RE_SEAT);

}
```

My test:

```
import store from "../../../app/config/configStore";
import * as module from '../../../app/actions/module';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store'


jest.mock('../../../app/config/configStore', () => {
    return {
        __esModule: true,
        default: configureStore([])({})
    };
 });


describe('module action', () => {

     console.log(store.getState()); 
     console.log(module.reseat());

   //it will print the 'real' store initial state based on the reducers on both cases :-(

...
...
...
```

I tried to follow the instructions on this link: https://remarkablemark.org/blog/2018/06/28/jest-mock-default-named-export/

It looks like my mock.jest isn't being called at all. Does anyone have any idea about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It looks like adding a transformer to jest configuration (package.json) was not letting the .mock works, not sure why.

I just removed the .js transformer  and it worked:

```
 "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js", //removed this line
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
```